# Stop the process on terminate event of a form in Vba

Tags: events, vba, process, terminate

How can I stop the process in the terminate event of a user form in vba. But I have to keep the excel sheet as not closed. Only stop the process.

Please help me friends

Comment: Please explain what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am running an xla addin for creating a particular folder structure based on the data in the excel sheet. User has to enter some details in the form for this. After starting the folder creation, if the user close the form using 'x' button or cancel button in the form, the folder creation process should has to terminate. This is my requirement.

Comment: I found one. but it close the excel work book also. I have to keep workbook opened.

Comment: Can you show the userform code?

Comment: No. Your code which is closing the excel sheet

Comment: @ Siddharth: now in btnCancel_Click() I just wrote 'unload me'. But it will not stop the process. Just close the form only. Process will continue.

Comment: I tried this. But it terminate the workbook. Sub Kill_Excel()

Dim sKillExcel As String

sKillExcel = "TASKKILL /F /IM Excel.exe"
Shell sKillExcel, vbHide

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if ErrCondition then End
```